# AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear is not clearing the sort fields

Tags: vba, sorting, autofilter

I have VBA code that uses the columns (values in the Rows section) of a Pivot table on one worksheet to sort another worksheet's data and then summarize that data.  Whenever the Pivot table changes the summarized data is recalculated by users pushing a command button.  After I run the AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear I'm still getting 13 sorts exist.  These are combinations of the previous sorts.  This continues to build up until I get a XLSM file is corrupt message.

```
Function SortTab(pSheet As String, pCol As String) As Boolean
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Sort entire tab by 1 to 5 columns
'
'Code examples from recording a Macro when sorting
'    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("I2:I1019"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("J2:J1019"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'
'Parameters:
' pSheet    Sheet to find range     Example: Data
' pCol      Last column on sheet    Example: BC100
'
'Global Variables:
' gRange        UsedRange for current sheet Example: A1:BC100
' gPivotCols    Array of column names to Sort   Example: gPivotCols(1) = 5 for "Dept", gPivotCols(2) =  4 for "Company"
' gColSort  Last column in the sort     Example: 4 for the Company column being the 4th column in the data sheet
'gColMax        Max # of Sort Columns is 5
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
On Error GoTo Err_SortTab
    
    Dim i           As Integer
       
    'Remove all Fiters & Sorts
    Worksheets(pSheet).Activate                             'Select sheet
    Worksheets(pSheet).AutoFilterMode = False               'Turn AutoFilter off
    Worksheets(pSheet).UsedRange.AutoFilter                 'Turn AutoFilter on
    Worksheets(pSheet).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear     'Clear any Sorts
    
'Code inserted to find out how many sort columns exist after a AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear   
'Currently returning a value of 13 sorts  
i = ExistingSorts()
If i > 0 Then
    MsgBox i & " existing sorts still exist", vbCritical, "Error"
    SortTab = False
    Exit Function
End If
    
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .Header = xlYes                 'Tab has Headers
        .MatchCase = False              'Not case sensitive
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom    'Sort Top to Bottom
        .SetRange Range(gRange)         'Complete range on Data tab to sort example: A1:BC100
        
        For i = 1 To gColMax            'Loop throuh column heading in the Pivot table
            If gPivotCols(i) = 0 Then   'Check for less than 5 columns
                Exit For
            End If
            gColSort = gPivotCols(i)    'Set the last column in the Sort
            
           .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(gRange).Columns(gColSort), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal       'Add sort column
            
        Next i
        .Apply
    End With


Exit_SortTab:
    SortTab = True
    Exit Function
    
Err_SortTab:
    If Application.UserName = "Murf" Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error #: " & Err.Number
        Stop
        Resume
    End If

End Function


Function ExistingSorts() As Integer
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Copied from internet
' Count existing sorts
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
On Error Resume Next

    Dim S   As Sort
    Dim SF  As SortField

    Set S = ActiveSheet.Sort
    
    ExistingSorts = S.SortFields.Count

End Function
```

I've tried several different variations of

- Worksheets(pSheet).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
- Activesheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
- with Activesheet
  .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear

The manual sorts created on the data tab disappear (arrows go away) but the actual data is sorted by whatever string of columns is already entered.

Comment: Would you be able to share an example worksheet with the pivot table and the end result you want to achieve? It's difficult to troubleshoot your issue without some testing. There may also be another approach to the issue.

Comment: If someone will show me how to upload a file I would be happy to

Comment: I created an example worksheet on Google Docs. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CFfcoXlCw0O2TmyuL4Zcmqwglj0SNzDV/view?usp=sharing